# Sending mouse click on different coordinates not working on a specific window

Tags: visual-c++

I have a code that sends mouse click (right button) to a chosen window but it does not work on a specific window. I tried to run it in my browser and it worked. Any idea why this happen?

This is my code:

```
POINT pt = { 974, 625 };

PostMessage(hwnd, WM_RBUTTONDOWN, MK_RBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y));
Sleep(20);
PostMessage(hwnd, WM_RBUTTONUP, MK_RBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y));
```

**EDIT:**
It works on the said "specific window" but it just clicked on the cursor's position. I want it to work on different coordinates regardless of my mouse cursor's position just like how it worked in other window(browser).

Comment: I imagine the application in question chooses to ignore the coordinates that come with the message, and instead reads the mouse position with `GetCursorPos` or similar.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik any idea how to bypass that?